# Bad configuration option in GIT (AllowUsers)

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, config

I'm trying to clone a project by using ssh from the gitlab repository, but the problem is that I can't do it because message `Permission denied: (publickey)`.

I have generated ssh key and added to my gitlab account, but it didn't worked out. Now I'm trying to add a config file into my ssh folder, which looks like this:

```
Host gitlab.com
    User user
    Hostname gitlab.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    TCPKeepAlive yes
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    AllowUsers user
```

But the GIT says: `Bad configuration option: allowusers`.

Could someone explain me why?

Comment: was the ssh key generated from the system that you are trying to take a clone to? and are you the sudo user?

Comment: I'm using git bash for the repository cloning. I cannot write sudo -l to check whether I am a sudo user... :(

Answer (score 3):

```
Host gitlab.com
    ...
    AllowUsers user
```

Remove the "AllowUsers" line from your `.ssh/config` file. The parameters accepted by ssh are described [here](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config), and "AllowUsers" isn't one of them.

"AllowUsers" is a parameter that can be set in the [OpenSSH server configuration](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config). In your case, the server here is gitlab.com, and even assuming they're using the stock OpenSSH server, you almost certainly don't have the ability or the need to reconfigure Gitlab's servers.

Comment: Tried to create a new sshd_config file and add a line `AllowUsers user`, but still have public key problem. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is that you remove "AllowUsers" from your ssh config and forget about it. Why are you trying to set AllowUsers in the first place? It's something you set on the server, and in this case Gitlab is the server.

Comment: And if you're having a "public key problem", that's a separate issue and you should ask a new question.

Comment: In line with Kenster's answer, I was getting this error because I accidentally put an AllowUsers clause in /etc/ssh/ssh_config instead of /etc/ssh/sshd_config where it belongs.  The AllowUsers clause was meant to keep unauthorized people from logging into my machine but I put it in the wrong place and hence got the Git error mentioned in this question.